# Angular navigation bar data is not being refreshed

Tags: angular, typescript

Service function

```
  public retrieveUserInfo(): Observable<User>{
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('token', localStorage.getItem("token"));
    return this.httpClient.get<User>("http://localhost:8080/api/retrieveUserInfo", {headers, responseType: 'json' as 'json' });
  }
```

This is my app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <app-navigation></app-navigation>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

navigation component ts

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  isShown:boolean = false;
  user: User;
  constructor(public apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.apiService.isUserLoggedIn()){
      this.retrieveUserInfoo();
    }
  }

  retrieveUserInfoo(){
    this.apiService.retrieveUserInfo().subscribe(
      res=> {
        this.user=res;
      },
    )
  }

}
```

This is my navigation component html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark pozadie mb-5">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Adam Mikeška</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" (click)="isShown = !isShown" [attr.aria-expanded]="isShown" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div [ngClass]="{ 'show': isShown }" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a [routerLink]="['/']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" class="nav-link">Home<i class="fa fa-home ml-1"></i> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li *ngIf="apiService.isUserLoggedIn()===false" class="nav-item">
        <a [routerLink]="['/login']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" class="nav-link">Login <i class="fa fa-sign-in ml-1"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="apiService.isUserLoggedIn()" class="nav-item">
        <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" class="nav-link">Dashboard<i class="fa fa-line-chart ml-1"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="apiService.isUserLoggedIn()" class="nav-item">
        <a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" class="nav-link">{{user.email}}<i class="fa fa-user ml-1"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="apiService.isUserLoggedIn()" class="nav-item">
        <a  [routerLink]="['/login']" (click)="apiService.logout()"  class="nav-link">Logout<i class="fa fa-sign-out ml-1"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="apiService.isUserLoggedIn()===false" class="nav-item">
        <a [routerLink]="['/register']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" class="nav-link">Register<i class="fa fa-sign-in ml-1"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

is user logged in

```
  public isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return !(user === null);
  }
```

The problem is navigation is not being refreshed after sucessfully login, so after login li a with user.email value is empty, and page need to be refreshed to display data.
Any solution?
Thanks

Comment: Show the definition for `ApiService.prototype.isUserLoggedIn`

Comment: I have added it, but i really dont think that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i done it this way
in service i made

```
private user = new BehaviorSubject<User>()


cast= this.user.asObservable();

editUser(newUser){
 this.user.next(newUser);
}
```

and then in login service

```
  retrieveUserInfo(){
    this.apiService.retrieveUserInfo().subscribe(
      res=> {
        this.apiService.cast.subscribe(result=> this.user = res);
        this.apiService.editUser(res);
      },
    )
  }
```

and in navigation this

```
 if(this.apiService.isUserLoggedIn()){
      this.apiService.cast.subscribe(user=> {this.user = user});
    }
```

So data appears instantly, but after refreshing page it disapears again :-D 
So i wonder if it is good to do it this way

```
 if(this.apiService.isUserLoggedIn()){
      this.apiService.cast.subscribe(user=> {this.user = user});
      this.retrieveUserInfo();
    }

  retrieveUserInfo(){
    this.apiService.retrieveUserInfo().subscribe(
      res=> {
        this.user=res;
      },
    )
  }
```

As this it works as it should but i dont know if im not missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think `apiService.isUserLoggedIn()` should be changed from a function to BehaviorSubject and make sure any auth state changes propagates through it. function is evaluated once in this example.

Example

```js
// in api service constructor
this.apiService.isUserLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject(false);
let user = localStorage.getItem('token');
this.apiService.isUserLoggedIn.next(user !== null);

// after sign in callback
this.apiService.isUserLoggedIn.next(true);

// NavigationComponent 
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe(value => {
      if(value) {
        this.retrieveUserInfoo();
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject ChangeDetectorRef in constructor

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

After successfully login please render the dom again by doing below code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.apiService.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe(value => {
  if(value) {
    this.retrieveUserInfoo();
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
})
```

}

It will trigger DOM update immediately.